# make a javaScript call to consume REST API running on localhost

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, rest, browser, cors

I have a java-springboot microservice running on port 8080 and localhost server. It looks like this :

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "")
    public User getUser() {
        return userService.getUser();
    }
}
```

I am trying to access the User data using the call "http://localhost:8080/user". While testing it through the browser and Postman the call is returning the data. But with javacript it is returning an empty response.

I am a newBee in js.

My javascript code loks like this:

```
function getCurrentUser()
{
    try
    {
        var userUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/user";
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            try
            {
                if (this.readyState == 4 ) {
                    var response = this.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("idCurrentName").innerHTML = response;              
                }
            }
            catch(erMs)
            {
                document.getElementById("idCurrentName").innerHTML = erMs;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", userUrl, true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        xhttp.send();
    }
    catch(erMsg)
    {
        document.getElementById("idCurrentName").innerHTML = erMsg;
    }
}
```

Please help in accessing the data on loclhost.
Thanks!!

Comment: First of all, check your browser console. You will likely find an error message in there, saying that this request has been blocked, because no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header was set in the response. If that is the case - then go read up on _CORS_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually related to CORS. I initially added a chrome browser extension, but then as I am using SpringBoot in the backend for my services, I added the annotation @CrossOrigin on my RestController. That fixed the CORS problem.

Hope it helps.

The backend code now looks like this:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/user")
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "")
    public User getUser() {
        return userService.getUser();
    }
}
```